# JavaScript Date does not reflect system time change in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, date

Implementing html+js clock timer ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2b6b2jp/1/) sample) and I found problem when changing operating system time backward and then forward.

Lets have this html:

```
<div id="time">-</div>
```

And JS code:

```
var time = document.getElementById('time');
function iteration() {
    time.innerHTML = new Date().toString();
}
setInterval(iteration, 100);
```

Lets say you started page at 2:22PM. Label display correct time.

Now change operating system local time backward 1 hour to 1:22PM, now JS `new Date()` correctly returns changed time 1:22PM.

Next change operating system local time forward to actual date - 2:22PM, and now JS `new Date()` does not return 2:22PM but old 1:22PM. So it seems to me that it does not handle correctly changes to local system time (forward only?).

Seems to be problem only in Google Chrome (37.0.2062.124 m (64-bit)).
In Internet Explorer and Firefox, JS `new Date()` return correct value.

Update: Does anyone know how to 'fix' this for Google chrome using JS code?

Comment: Interesting. But I must ask, why would you do switch your OS time back and forth?

Comment: Is this a question, or a bug report?

Comment: I have site to test user knowledge, where is timer(countdown) with time to which must user finish his test, lets say 20minutes. I need to track elapsed time, so i created 'stopwatch'. But standard js implementation (found many of them on web) use `new Date().getTime() - startTime` but this does not survive such local time changes. With such local time changes user adds more time for testing session. Sure we have check for time on server and does not allow it. But we also want to handle client side.

Comment: David Thomas: It is question how to fix this behaviour for Google Chrome, other than waiting for fix from Google. Of course if it is possible.

Comment: Why downvote? I have serious problem, maybe related to Google product, but need help to find workaround for that..

Comment: I am not alone! Indeed, When changing OS time 1 day back and then 1 day forward, the new Date() still returns yesterday date! (but works in IE and Firefox). I just wanted to test one thing , but  met this

Comment: I found out the certain rules about this.
If you change the time to the future, Chrome's new Date() refresh after 30~60 seconds later.
But change the time to the past, new Date() refresh immediately.

Comment: @sayingu so the question (to chrome team) is if this is by design (then need to explain why) or if it's bug, need to fix it!